# Free equivalent to diffzilla?

Tags: windows-xp

I two sets of files with directories in a tree structure in two different "root" directories. The files are mostly identical, but a few have some minor edits. Can anyone recommend some free software that would help me quickly identify which files have changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

short answer.

winmerge: http://winmerge.org/

Comment: It looks to me like I still have to manually click through all the complex directory structure in order to see the list of different files. I can't work out how to see all the different files at the same time.

Comment: It defo does directory level comparisons, in fact it says so right on the homepage of it. Im a linux user so i use linux tools, but i know the windows people here swear by winmerge. http://winmerge.org/docs/tour/#tour_comparingdirs